# eclipse - how to make required gems auto-completable

Tags: ruby, eclipse, autocomplete

I'm using eclipse for ruby development and I have installed the Ruby Development Tools plugin.  Seems eclipse doesn't auto-complete required gems, for example

require "gemA"

a = gemA.new

a.  # no auto-completion

Is there a way to make it work in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [JetBrain's Ruby Mine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/). It's not free, but I've heard it's worth the money.

Also, I doubt eclipse has auto-completion for that plug-in. To make sure, check your IDE preferences that auto-completion is enabled.